# Closing questions that are not questions: what to pick?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, close-reasons

It happens regularly that a user complains about something but does not have a question.

When voting to close, would it make sense to have the option "not a question", or otherwise at least add this reason to the description of the "Needs details or clarity" option?

Comment: If at all possible, try to ask (friendly) what the question is and edit the question. Some people (mostly, people who are not in mathematics or comp. Science) are not used the strict style here and believe it is clear what question they ask because it is implied in their post.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per site, we have limited freedom in what we can modify in the close dialog. Specifically, we can only modify the *community-specific reasons*, and we cannot add further options (see note below about the details).

I suggest you to use the option "Needs details or clarity", as imperfect as it is, because the poster needs anyway to clarify what is the question. Note that this option is global for the whole network, and the likelihood of such a change—given the backlog and the priorities of the Stack Exchange staff—is probably tiny.

*Note*: Specifically, with the exception of Stack Overflow, standard sites have a limit of three community-specific close reasons, and we have already reached this limit. If there is a really strong case, and consensus about its need, a site can ask to have a fourth community-specific reason, but it's generally discouraged. About your suggestion, I can hardly see making a strong case around it.

Comment: Just for additional history, [a long time ago, there was actually "Not a real question" close reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171732/241919)... which later got refined into "unclear what you're asking" (among the rest) which then became the current "needs detail or clarity".